# Sails js throws error - Unknown Rule isIn

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I've created a modal in sails.js with [isIn validation rule](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations) following attribute:

```
    visibility:{
        type:"string",
        isIn: ['private', 'public' ]
    },
```

It is throwing an error while creating the data:

[image]

Can anybody suggest solution for this?

Comment: if you only have two possible options why not make it a boolean?

Comment: Also `"string"` should be in single quotes => `'string'`

Comment: @Raqem List may expand. I tried with single quotes, its same error.

Comment: Double or single quote does not matter at all. Vishnu were you able to solve this yet?

Comment: I was not able to solve, so I removed `isIn` operator from `model` itself as it was blocking.

Comment: Don't think it's still relevant), but I faced the same issue. @Vishnu, looks like you're using sails `v0.12`, not `v1.0`. Replacing `isIn` with `in` or `enum` works for me. It's really difficult to find any docs regarding this issue(expects [this one](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4393)) so I decided to post it here.